How to get path of the pointed document from the Product Instance which is not loaded in CATIA V5 by using CATIA V5 CAA
I want to know how to get the full path of unretrieved link to reference from the broken product in CATIA V5 using CAA.
I have used CATIAttributesDescription and CATIInstance in my CAA code, but not very helpful.
There is way to get if I use the method GetDocFileName() from the interface CATIxPDMItem. It is from CATxPDMInterfaces, but I want to the Product Structure API to get the full path.
